# Erlang: Why don't I see error_logger:info_msg output when connected by remsh?

Tags: erlang

I connect to a running node with the -remsh flag, and I run my usual Common Test sanity tests, but none of the error_logger:info_msg messages appear in the shell. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SASL default event handler will only write events to console/tty of the local node.
When connecting via "-remsh", you're starting a second node and communicating via
message passing to the first.  The output from the "nodes()" BIF can confirm this.

Calls to the error_logger functions will send events to the local 'error_logger' 
registered process, which is a gen_event server.  You can manipulate it using
error_logger:tty/1 and error_logger:logfile/1, see the reference docs in the "Basic"
Application Group, then the "kernel" application, then the "error_logger" module.

You can also add your own event handler to the 'error_logger' server, which can then
do anything you want with the event.  I'd guess that error_logger:logfile/1 might be
sufficient for your purposes, though.

-Scott